# the background colour is not being changed in python no matter what I do on mac. But it works fine on windows. Why is that?

Tags: tkinter

background color of the button is not changing no matter what color I give on mac. How can I fix this?

```
from tkinter import *
    root=Tk()
    Label(root, text= "Hello World").pack()
    frame1=Frame(root)
    frame1.pack()
    button= Button(frame1,text="Login",fg="yellow", bg="red")
    button.pack()
    root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Can u fix indentation? Ur code is working.

Comment: Please edit post and mention abt MAC, and add tag too

Comment: If you are running this on a macintosh, you cannot change the background color of buttons.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed the indentation. Ur code is working

```
from tkinter import *
root=Tk()
Label(root, text= "Hello World").pack()
frame1=Frame(root)
frame1.pack()
button= Button(frame1,text="Login",fg="yellow", bg="red")
button.pack()
root.mainloop()
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: Thank you. I tried this on my windows and it works just fine. But on my mac it doesn't. Why's that?

Comment: U didn't mention abt MAC?

Comment: Here is link. https://www.python.org/download/mac/tcltk/